# is check required in this situation

Tags: c++, if-statement, mfc

In C++ I read a coding guideline as "check return value in If control statement"
Like,

```
if(TRUE == fun1())
{
//Statements
}
```

When "fun1" returns True, internally in "if" statement it will be compared with “true”.
Is it necessary to compare externally.?
Is this a good practice or is this style of coding decreases performance.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparing to TRUE is never a good idea.

If fun1 returns a BOOL, than its value is in fact an int and can have any int value. TRUE is just 1, FALSE is 0. But there are a lot of other values for an int. Comparing to FALSE is always save!

In a lot of cases. Functions return "something" and that should mean "TRUE" (!=0) as long as it is different from 0!

As long as you have a bool return value you can compare to true and false and it will always work.

It depends on the style, but I never use an expression to compare to a TRUE value (meaning not 0, not false). I always write the condition without an operator in the if statement. And it has the meaning for me "If fun1 is something" or "If fun1 succeeded"

```
if (fun1())
{
//Statements
}
```

In our company this is the normal coding style. And if we want to check the reverse. "If fun1 fails"

```
if (!fun1())
{
}
```

With modern compilers and processors there is no real speed impact.

Comment: If `fun1` returns a `BOOL`, then the expression `if(fun1())` is likely to generate a compiler warning. `if(fun1()!=FALSE)` prevents that warning.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the return type of `fun1` and the type of `TRUE`.

If `TRUE` is `true` and `fun1` returns `bool`, it doesn't decrease performance, because it does exactly what the `if` does itself. So it's just no-op clutter.

With other types, it looks dangerous and could even be wrong. Imagine a legacy-style function which returns `int` and is documented to return 0 on failure and a non-zero value on success (quite a few C standard library functions are like that). Then, let's say `TRUE` is `true` or `1`. In this case, the function returning 2 (a perfectly valid non-zero value) would actually *fail* the condition!

So unless the types and values are so perverted that `TRUE` is `0` (which is not the case with MFC), I'd say it's actually *harmful* to compare with it.

Comment: The question is tagged MFC, which is pretty old but not that insane. I'm certain that `TRUE` is non-zero in MFC.

Comment: If we consider only the case of MFC coding then i guess that coding style can be adopted.. if not correct me please..

Comment: @nandeesh I still recommend against it. It will fail you as soon as `fun1()` returns something else than a boolean.